# Jquery prevent multiple function calls

Tags: php, jquery

I have been implementing a like and dislike system. The code is below:

```
<span class="col-5 l bbox" onclick="like('.$id.');"><img src="/img/like.png" /></span>
```

As you can see above, when the user clicks on above like block, I have created a function call which registers a `like` in the system through ajax call.

Here, the `$id` is the post_id which I am passing to the function.

The code is below:

```
function like(id) {
  var pid = id;
  $.ajax({
       url: '/like.php?id=' + pid,
       type: "get",
  }).done(function(data) {
     $('#like' + pid).html(data);
    });
}
```

But, the problem here is, a single user can click on `like` as many times as he wants and the system still registers the likes.

I want to implement a system in which users can only register a single like or dislike for a single post or single `$id`.

Comment: Then do a select on the id to check if its already been liked before allowing it to go through

Comment: Do this on the server side. Setup your system so that it only ever creates one record for the users like/dislike choice. I'd also suggest using unobtrusive event handlers instead of the massively outdated `on*` event attributes

Comment: can't you handle this on the like.php page? Return false or an error on fail after first doing a select on the id?

Comment: you can use  `this.id` in onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to remove the onclick attribute immediatelly, like following:

```
onclick="like('.$id.'); $(this).attr(\'onclick\',\'\');"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you first render the page you have to show this HTML if the user has never clicked the like or dislike button

```
<span id="preference-container">
  <span id="like-span" class="col-5 l bbox" onclick="like('.$id.', true);">
    <img src="/img/like.png" />
  </span>
  <span id="dislike-span" class="col-5 l bbox" onclick="like('.$id.', false);">
    <img src="/img/dislike.png" />
  </span>
</span>
```

if the user already clicked the like button you have to show this HTML

```
<span id="preference-container">
  <span id="dislike-span" class="col-5 l bbox" onclick="like('.$id.', false);">
    <img src="/img/dislike.png" />
  </span>
</span>
```

otherwise you show this HTML

```
<span id="preference-container">
  <span id="like-span" class="col-5 l bbox" onclick="like('.$id.', true);">
    <img src="/img/like.png" />
  </span>
</span>
```

then on the like function you have to dinamically change the preference button

```
var LIKE_BUTTON =   
  "<span id='like-span' class='col-5 l bbox' onclick='like(\".$id.\", true);'>" +  
  "  <img src='/img/like.png' />" +  
  "</span>";

var DISLIKE_BUTTON =   
  "<span id='dislike-span' class='col-5 l bbox' onclick='like(\".$id.\", false);'>" +  
  "  <img src='/img/dislike.png' />" +  
  "</span>";

function like(id, like) {   
     var pid = id;   
     $.ajax({
       url: '/like.php?id=' + pid + '&like=' + (like ? "true" : "false"),
       type: "get",   
    }).done(function(data) {
       $('#like' + pid).html(data);

       $("#preference-container").empty().append($(like ? DISLIKE_BUTTON : LIKE_BUTTON));

  }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside like.php you would need to check the user id against the post id to avoid duplicate likes. If it's guests (users not logged in) then maybe record some identifier e.g. ip?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to handle this from client side as to add data attribute to manage the state of like or dislike button:

```
like($id) {
  var state = $(this).data('isactive');
  if(!state) {
    // your ajax function
    $(this).data('isactive', true);
  }
}


dislike($id) {
  var state = $(this).data('isactive');
  if(!state) {
    // your ajax function
    $(this).data('isactive', true);
  }
}
```

and also manage if user click on like button then set the data-isactive attribute to false and vice versa. You can maintain the button state in local-storage of browser.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Removing attribute `onclick` immediately after the function call:

```
<span class="col-5 l bbox" onclick="like('.$id.'); $(this).removeAttr(\'onclick\');"><img src="/img/like.png" /></span>
```